# The correct Grok Parser for Django in ELK stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to use the ELK stack for my application logging. Everything runs well, with the exception of the log filter in the logstash. I can't seem to get the grok to parse successfully.

My current settings:

```
if [type] == "djangolog" {
    multiline {
        pattern => "^[^\[]"
        what => "previous"
    }

    grok {
        match => { "message" => "\[%{LOGLEVEL:level}\] \[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{WORD:module}\] \[%{POSINT:process}\] - %{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}" }
    }

    date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    }
}
```

Sample Django Log that I'm trying to index:

```
[DEBUG] [2018-07-11 10:16:07,035] [9763] [func.get_func:366] - get func time 0.14696598053
```

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong and references would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third field in your sample message is an INT, but your grok pattern waits for a WORD, this will give you a `grokparsefailure` error.

Testing your sample message with the grok debugger in Kibana, the following pattern would match it.

I've changed the `%{WORD:module}` to `%{INT:module}`, but you could also use `%{DATA:module}`, it would match basically any string, as I did for the `process` field in the pattern .

```
\[%{LOGLEVEL:level}\] \[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{INT:module}\] \[%{DATA:process}\] - %{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}
```

[image: grok debugger]

Comment: It's the grok debugger in Kibana, if you use X-pack, even the free basic license you have it, but if you do not have Kibana with X-pack, you can use this website: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/, it is the same implementation.